# Как воспользоваться классом Entity из пакета django-eav, чтобы использовать его методы в своем классе?

Tags: python, django

Нужно, чтобы объекты моего класса видели методы get_all_attributes, get_values и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Я разобрался

```
@property
def entity(self):
    return Entity(self)
```

А дальше можно использовать

```
p.entity.get_values()
p.entity.get_all_attributes()
```